# 2008 Chev 3.5 studder

Tags: engine, chevrolet

I have a newly rebuilt 2008 Chevrolet Impala 3.5. When newly rebuilt, purred like a kitten. Now at an idle, I'll get a very short studder in rpm, almost like a miss. Happens about every 10 seconds. When i rebuilt it, put new spark plugs in. Could this be wires (they're original) or a bad plug? Or worse yet, ignition module?

Comment: 08 chevrolet what?

Comment: Editted:  Impala

Comment: Any codes in the computer?

Comment: P0442 -Evap emission ctl leak -Small. However it's been there since I rebuilt the motor. The studder is new.

Comment: If it is a misfire, it probably isn't frequent enough to set a code, or greater than 2%.  The fact that it it a GM vehicle, most scan tools (even $5 torque pro) are capable of displaying cylinder specific misfire counters.  Otherwise pull all of the plug wires and look for carbon tracking.

Comment: I would look for vacuum leaks also.